# Force number precision in a view with Union

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I am using Entity Framework and Oracle. Oracle's ODAC seems to have a known bug where data of type NUMBER is cast to Int64 by Entity Framework.  I thought a view would assist me but

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test as
select 1 AS ONE ,CAST(2 AS NUMBER(1)) AS TWO ,CAST(3 as INT) AS THREE from dual
union
select 1 AS ONE ,CAST(2 AS NUMBER(1)) AS TWO ,CAST(3 as INT) AS THREE from dual
```

When you look at the view the data type is Number with no precision for all of them.  This appears to be a consequence of the UNION as just

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test as
select 1 AS ONE ,CAST(2 AS NUMBER(1)) AS TWO ,CAST(3 as INT) AS THREE from dual
```

yields NUMBER, NUMBER(1), NUMBER as the datatypes

Is there a workaround to force Oracle to derive a precision in a view with a UNION?

Edit: @Phil asks the desired result is. He is correct that Entity Framework has to have a precision to work with so the desired datatype from the sample above would be
NUMBER(1)

Edit: @Phil for this version Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Windows 32 bit a view with a union gives a view that has NUMBER with no precision.  Entity Framework interprets this as int 64.

I am looking for a solution that shows the NUMBERS with a precision that Entity Framework can understand as a 32 bit integer.  Any precision from NUMBER(1) to NUMBER (9) does the job.

Comment: So, you're trying to get Entity Framework to cast to a Double? Have you seen the table on this page? http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/DatatypeMapping.html The `NUMBER()` has to have a scale for Entity Framework to cast appropriately.

Comment: Is it a double you're trying to get EF to cast to?

Comment: Sorry Phil, the desired result is NUMBER(1)

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking at the bigger picture. EF is casting to an Int64 - What data type do you actually want it to cast to?

Comment: Also, I get `NUMBER`, `NUMBER(1)`, `NUMBER(38)` for the datatypes when trying your `UNION` test view on 11.2.0.2.0 64-bit Linux.

Comment: Maybe you're confused too. To cast as a floating point you need a precision and scale, so you'll need `NUMBER(p,s)` not just `NUMBER(p)` (which is equivalent to `NUMBER(p,0)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test as 
select 1 AS ONE ,CAST(2 AS NUMBER(1)) AS TWO ,CAST(3 as INT) AS THREE from dual
```

gives you what you want, why not use the same for union :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test_v11 as
SELECT ONE, CAST(TWO AS NUMBER(1)) AS TWO, CAST(THREE AS INT) AS THREE
FROM 
(
 SELECT 1 AS ONE ,2 AS TWO ,3 AS THREE FROM dual
  UNION
 SELECT 1 AS ONE ,2 AS TWO ,3 AS THREE FROM dual
 )a
```

Comment: I am away from my desk but that looks interesting. What is the precision when you run it?

Comment: @kevinsky: the second view shows the same precision as the first - ` NUMBER, NUMBER(1), NUMBER `

Comment: good answer, using CAST on the overall select works fine and gives a view with the column precision of NUMBER(1).